# How to make loop with multi-core computation in VC++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, multicore

No idea about multi-core parallelization. But for simple loops, it might modify little. For the following example, how to make simple loops with multi-core computation in VC++?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

void foo(int n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int m = 1001001;
    vector<double> a(m), b(m), c(m), d(m), f(m);

    std::clock_t startcputime = std::clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        foo(1000000, &a[0], &b[0], &c[0], &d[0], &d[1], &f[0], &f[1000]);
    double cpu_duration = (std::clock() - startcputime) / (double)CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << "Finished in " << cpu_duration << " seconds [CPU Clock] " << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: [OpenMP](http://openmp.org/wp/), [OpenCL](https://www.khronos.org/opencl/), [OpenACC](http://www.openacc.org/).

Comment: I believe that your first step should be to study basics of concurrency and parallelism, so that you have "some idea".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `concurrency` namespace in the Parallel Patterns Library (part of VC++) contains `parallel_for` which is exactly what you want.

```
void parallel_foo(int n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    concurrency::parallel_for(static_cast<size_t>(0), static_cast<size_t>(n), [&](size_t i) {
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
    });
}
```

I'd recommend using `size_t` for 'n'. This way it gets a little cleaner:

```
void parallel_foo(size_t n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    concurrency::parallel_for(0, n, [&](size_t i) {
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
    });
}
```

You should also take a look at the example at [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728073.aspx)

You could use 'amp' as an alternative. Its more powerfull and more complex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `OpenMP`, just add `#pragma omp parallel for` before `for` loop.

```
void foo(int n, double* a, double* b, double *c, double*d, double* e, double* f, double* g)
{
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = b[i] * a[i] + c[i] * (d[i] + e[i] + f[i] + g[i]);
    }
}
```

Also, if you using Microsoft Visual studio, you need to enable `OpenMP Support` in settings

1. Open the project's Property Pages dialog box.
2. Expand the Configuration Properties node.
3. Expand the C/C++ node.
4. Select the Language property page.
5. Modify the OpenMP Support property.